# Django - custom registration form (errors, unique email and admin)

Tags: python, django, forms, registration

first of all, I am new in programming with Django. Here is what I have:

The `<form>` inside my **register.html** template:

```
<form method='POST' action='/accounts/register/'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }} {{field.help_text}} {{field.errors}{}
   <br/>
   {% endfor %}
   <input type='submit' value='Register' />
</form>
```

This is inside my **forms.py**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
first_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
last_name = forms.CharField(required = True)
password1 = forms.RegexField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            regex = r'[\w+]{8,}',
                            label = 'New password',
                            help_text = "Must be strong!",
                            error_messages = {'required' : "ASDASDA",
                                              'invalid' : "ZZZZZ"}
                            )
password2 = forms.RegexField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            regex = r'[\w+]{8,}',
                            label = 'Re-enter password',
                            )

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

def save(self, commit = True):
    user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

This is inside my **views.py**

```
def User_Register_View(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        register_success = "Account successfuly created!"
        return render(request,'index.html', locals())

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

return render(request,'accounts/register.html',args)
```

My questions are the following:

1. {{field.errors}} is not working. No errors are printed. If I let all the fields of the form empty, and I click 'Register', no error is rendered.
2. If I add another field to this forum, "gender" as a CharField, will it create a column inside my DB for gender? ( I am working with the default sqlite3)
3. Is there a simple way to modify my code and make the 'User' field optional and, instead, make the 'Email' field be unique and required?
4. In the state in which my code is, where can I check for the unique property of my email in the DB? Is it inside my views.py, just before form.save() ?

Thank you. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2):

```
def User_Register_View(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          register_success = "Account successfuly created!"
          return render(request,'index.html', locals())
    else:
        form = MyRegistrationForm() # An unbound form

    args = {}
    args['form'] = form

    return render(request,'accounts/register.html',args)
```

1. {{field.errors}} now showing because you are not returning the validated form instance if  validation failed. You always return a new instance of MyRegistrationForm. See above example.
2. adding fields to forms will not affect your db since only models maps to db tables
3. & 4. You need custom user model to do so, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) for example on how to do it

Comment: MyRegistrationForm is a sub class of UserCreationForm. I've just extended it to introduce the email field.

Comment: 2. True and logical. But then, how can I request for new fields at registration and insert them in the DB?

Comment: sorry I missed that. For new fields, you have two options, either use custom User model or use a one to one model as a user profile. check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: and I highly recommend you go with some package that take care of all this stuff for you, like django-allauth, it is really easy and flexible   to configure  and use